# Is Magento Certification advisable as Magento 2 is coming soon

Tags: discussion, suggestion

I was thinking of taking Magento Certification exam, but a question popped up my mind. As Magento 2 is expected to come early next year is it advisable to take the certification exam now as I assume Magento 2 won't be backward compatible and its core code structure has changed too.

So will the current certification hold the same value as it is now? Will there be a new certification exam for Magento 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have decided that certification is something you want to do then I would say it's still worth it yes.  A few months ago release candidate was slated for March next year with full release slated for the end of next year.  No idea if that's still the case now and I don't know if anyone really knows if this is accurate (it was also slated for beta release in December this year - I'll be surprised tbh) - if anything it's probably case scenario.  Even if Magento 2 is released sooner rather than later, if you are looking to become certified to improve your profile as a developer and so get more development work then there will be plenty of Magento 1 projects out there for a very long time to come, well after Magento 2 sees the light of day.

Comment: you can assume the milestones will get released in time, there are no hints they will get delayed.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon - got the email about Magento 2 beta release in December this morning ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dexter, Magento 2 will be released on December 2015 in production version so it's plenty of time.

I think it's still worth to take Magento 1 exam, for sure Magento 1 stores will be around for years and they will still need to get developer's support.

Comment: I agree with you but if we take exam now then we might also need to take for magento 2 . So isnt better to wait for magento 2 ? i am also in same situation as @dexter

Comment: If you aim to work only on M2, it can make sense to wait. If you want to continue working on M1 projects, it makes sense to pass this exam.

Comment: yes I will continue working on M1 .